# Texture 'swimming' when moving mesh in edit mode

Tags: texturing, uv

I inherited a file from someone else, and all the textures appear to 'swim' when i move the mesh in edit mode. This happens whether i use UV, generated, object, etc texture coordinates. I'm sure this is a real noob fix but its driving me mad!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the *Correct Face Attributes* option:

[image]

Comment: oh my god thank you. its like finally getting a splinter out or freeing something stuck in your teeth. a single check box, so much frustration. thanks!

Comment: this option should not be activated by default so you could have just copied pasted or appended your object in a brand new file, but it's always better to understand why it doesn't work I guess